# Where is the Software Sources Window?

Tags: software-center

I am running Ubuntu 13, and would like to configure my updates and sources of software. Every piece of documentation I see indicates that to do this I use a "Software Sources" window that is supposed to be available through System Settings (System Settings ->Software Sources).

The System Settings window on Ubuntu 13 does not appear to have a Software Sources selection.

Where is that window and how do I get to it???

Comment: If you go to system settings, click on Software and Updates when that loads, click on the Other Software Tab

Answer (score 2):

It's named "Software & Updates":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to type `sources` in the dash.

Comment: and then open "software & Updates" see answer below.